# Grothendieck's motivation of crystalline cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-hodge-theory, crystalline-cohomology

[Here](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~illusie/Illusie-Sapporo1.pdf) Illusie mentions Grothendieck's observation that using Gauss-Manin connection one can give a non-canonical isomorphism between de Rham cohomology of smooth schemes over $W(k)$ with isomorphic reductions to $k$.

I understand that the formula written there is just the Taylor expansion of a given cohomology class. It seems reasonable that divided powers are involved.

Is there a reference for this observation in general and for the convergence of the series?

Comment: Grothendieck's article on deRham cohomology in the book "Dix Exposes..." includes his notion of the "infinitesimal site" that gives a site-theoretic interpretation of algebraic deRham cohomology in the smooth proper case over a field of characteristic zero.  This was the first source of motivation for crystalline cohomology (as mentioned early in the book of Berthelot and Ogus).

Comment: @nfdc23 Sure, I understand this motivation, I should have probably name the question differently. I am asking about another motivation which can be formulated as "Crystalline cohomology established a canonical isomorphism between de Rham cohomology of liftings" and the question is why a non-canonical isomorphism can be proen without crystalline cohomology.

Comment: Have you read the rest of Grothendieck's paper?  He discusses Monsky-Washnitzer's *canonical* isomorphism (announced in unpublished work), and relates integrable connections to the notion of "stratification" -- a compatible system of "$n$-connections" for all $n \ge 1$ -- via his viewpoint of an infinitesimal descent-data formalism using iterated diagonals. The Appendix notes that integrable (1-)connections uniquely enhance to stratifications in char. 0 (see Theorem 2.15 in the Berthelot-Ogus book for a proof) but that this fails in residue char. $p>0$: see 3.5 in that paper, and 7.4 too.